# how to add keyboard events to textinputcells in a datagrid's cell?

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

I wanna know a mean to add events in a InputTextCell.
This event must to be yet:
"When a user press tab, the next cell will receive the focus, this one will be in other column."

I tried to use onBrowserEvent, but i don't found a mean to find other cell.

Answer (score 0):

You do it in the CellPreviewHandler:

```
myTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<T>() {
    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {
        if ("keydown".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
            int col = event.getContext().getColumn();
            int row = event.getContext().getIndex();
            if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == 9) {
                col++;
                if (col == getColumnCount()) {
                    col = 0;
                }
                getRowElement(row).getCells().getItem(col).getFirstChildElement().getFirstChildElement().focus();
            }
        }
    });
```